# How automatically float element in center of DIV when selected in HTML

Tags: html, css, scrollview

1. I have made vertical scroll view. Using `ul li` in a `div`. I have given fixed height to the `div` so that only 3 `li`s are visible. I want to bring the selected `li` to center when clicked.
   E.g. if I click 3, it should scroll to center.
2. When `li` goes out of scrollview I want to change its color
   ex. while scrolling when li 1 is going outside of scrollview it should change its color

Is there any way to do that in HTML/CSS?

[image]

```css
$container-background: #0F1012;
$subitem-color:orange;
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $container-background;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
}

.addMargin {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px
}

.sub-item {
  background-color: $subitem-color;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.features {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-item span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.sub-item:hover {
  background-color: #d0cdcd;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <ul class="features">
      <li class="sub-item">&#8364 20 <span>+10% Belwarde</span></li>
      <li class="sub-item">&#8364 20 <span>+10% Belwarde</span></li>
      <li class="sub-item">&#8364 20 <span>+10% Belwarde</span></li>
      <li class="sub-item">&#8364 20 <span>+10% Belwarde</span></li>
      <li class="sub-item">&#8364 20 <span>+10% Belwarde</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the code what you tried so far.

Comment: @Chilll007please find code and suggest way

Comment: you have do to do it using some jquery on click to make the li in center. does you done anything like that on click?